# How to create a Param with changeable size in Pyomo?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo

I'm new to Pyomo and there is a NumPy array-like `np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]...])` which represents the predict trajectories (position) of surrounding vehicles, and the first dimension represents the number of surrounding vehicles, the second dimension represents the predicted horizon.

For I use Pyomo to calculate the action of ego vehicle at every time step, and the number of surrounding vehicles is changing at every time step, the shape of the first dimension of the array is always changing, and these predict trajectories are used for calculating the objective function, like `obj = Σx`, `x` represents the predicted trajectory, the number of surrounding vehicles decides the number of items, to sum up, for example, now there are 2 surrounding vehicles, `obj = x0+x1`, at next time step, there are 3 surrounding vehicles, so `obj = x0+x1+x2`, so I wonder how to create a Param with changeable RangeSet and put the changeable 2-dimension NumPy array into the Param or there is any other method to combine the objective function with the changing input.

My idea is as follows:

```python
m = ConcreteModel()
m.num = Param(RangeSet(0,0),default= 0, mutable=True)  
m.x = Param(RangeSet(0,value(m.num[0])-1),RangeSet(0,3), mutable=True)

x0 = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
m.num.reconstruct({0:x0.shape[0]})
m.x.reconstruct()
m.pprint()
```

but the shape of `m.x` doesn't change:

```txt
1 Set Declarations
    x_index : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=True
        Key  : Dimen : Domain              : Size : Members
        None :     2 : x_index_0*x_index_1 :    0 :      {}

3 RangeSet Declarations
    num_index : Dimen=1, Size=1, Bounds=(0, 0)
        Key  : Finite : Members
        None :   True :     [0]
    x_index_0 : Dimen=1, Size=0, Bounds=(None, None)
        Key  : Finite : Members
        None :   True :      []
    x_index_1 : Dimen=1, Size=4, Bounds=(0, 3)
        Key  : Finite : Members
        None :   True :   [0:3]

2 Param Declarations
    num : Size=1, Index=num_index, Domain=Any, Default=0, Mutable=True
        Key : Value
          0 :     2
    x : Size=0, Index=x_index, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=True
        Key : Value

6 Declarations: num_index num x_index_0 x_index_1 x_index x
```

Maybe my method is quite wrong, I sincerely hope for any help.

Comment: Can you edit your post and explain a bit more why the param needs to change?  It isn’t clear what you are trying to do.  `pyomo` builds an instance of a model and hands it to a solver… so at some point, the dust has to settle for the model to be built.  If things change, you can make a new instance of the model (and change almost whatever you like) and re-solve.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have edited the post and I think it is different from the situation in your comment.

Comment: I don't think this is a good fit for pyomo...  I think from what you say above that you are running a time step simulation...  It would be difficult to see how to use an optimization model to fit into this.  Are you saying you have a math model written (that you have tested to see how long it takes to solve, gives good result, etc.) that you intend to solve at every time step?

Comment: FYI, `reconstruct()` method has been removed from `main` Branch in `Pyomo`. See the [Pyomo issue in Github](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/pull/1983).

Comment: @AirSquid Yes, it need to be solved every time step and I have tried the objective function without ```obj = Σx``` and its time cost is low enough, now I try to add ```obj = Σx``` to the former obj.

Comment: @pybegginer Thanks a lot, I use an old version, how to update the parameter and constraint like ```reconstruct()```  now?

Comment: As Airsquid said, I don't know if this time-step solving process is the best fit to Pyomo. If you want to implement this, I think that creating an `AbtractModel()`  is the best way to use it. You can parameterize any `Var` and `Constraint` in terms of a non-constructed set `model.T = pyo.Set()` and then create a new instance each time with the new ammount of cars.